# Is there a way to see the current address of a range object in VBA watch window/locals?

Tags: excel, vba

It's all in the title, really.  I want to be able to go to the locals window and from in there see the address of the range object but I can't find it.  Is it in there? I know you can see the values but I just want to see the full address like: "A1:D5" or whatever.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, The [Range.Address Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address).

Comment: Or just type `?theRangeObject.Address` in the *Immediate* toolwindow (Ctrl+G).

Comment: Can I not see it in the locals window so that I can access all of the ranges' addresses at any time?  Or the watch window?

Comment: I don't believe any property with arguments will show in the watch window. Address has 5 optional arguments. Same reason value isn't in there but value 2 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Range.Address Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) will print the address to the immediate window.

Or as mentioned in comments, just type `?YourRangeReference.Address` directly into the immidiate window to print the address value.

Here is a snip of a test routine with adding the `x.Address` expression to the watch list (where `x` is a `Range` variable):

[image: Watch window example]

I wasn't able to locate the value in the *locals window* but I assume it's in there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I think I did read something like this somewhere else but I didn't really understand it.  I think I do now, so thank you!